# A subtle trap in the definition of the smooth parametrized curve

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I'm trying to deal with the following (I guess there are standard) definitions of curves and smoothness.

Let's say we have a continuous function $r: [a;b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, then the image of this function is called a *curve*, and the function $r$ is called a *parametrization* of this curve. Obviously any curve can have infinitely many parametrizations.

Next, a point $(x;y)$ on a curve is called a *regular point* if there exists such a parametrization $r(t)$ that $(x; y)$ has exactly one preimage $t_0$, function $r$ is differentiable at this point and $r'(t_0) \neq 0$. If $(x; y)$ is not a regular point, it is called a *singular point* (i.e. if there is no such parametrization as described above).

A curve is called *continuously differentiable* if there is such a parametrization $r(t)$ that $r$ is continuously differentiable.

Finally, a curve is called *smooth* if it is continuously differentiable and does not have singular points.

But here comes a puzzle. If we treat the above definition formally, then it becomes:

$\gamma$ is smooth $\Leftrightarrow$ ( $\exists r(t): r'(t)$ is continuous ) AND ( $\forall (x;y) \in \gamma \;\; \exists r(t)$: $(x;y)$ is a regular point).

In other words, there is some parametrization in which our curve is continuously differentiable, and for each point of curve there is another (possibly different) parametrization in which this point is a regular point? Did we seriously mean that in our definition of smoothness?

For me it seems more natural to say: a curve is called smooth if there is **one** parametrization, such that it is continuously differentiable and all points are regular. Obviously this definition is more strict than the initial one.

So, my question: is there a difference between these two definitions of a smooth curve? Does there exist an example of a curve which is smooth according to initial definition but not smooth according to my definition? If such an example exists, which definition of smoothness should I prefer?

Comment: Please, add references to your definitions, since some are nonstandard. From my viewpoint, the difficulties with your definitions are artificial, caused by bad choice of definitions.